# How do I get the comma separated values from an NSMutableString in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, csv, nsmutablestring

I making an HTTP request in Objective-C and I get the reply from that is

> 200,8,"7 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA 95014, USA"

I want to extract the part "Cupertino, CA" from it.
I wrote the following code:

```
NSArray *myArray = [result5 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"Response: %@", myArray);
NSString * state = [[myArray objectAtIndex:4]
               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:@"[^0-9]" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"Response9: %@", state);
NSString *city = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", 
                           [myArray objectAtIndex:3], state];
NSLog(@"Response1: %@", city);
```

But I got a warning for the line:

```
NSString * state = [[myArray objectAtIndex:4]
             stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:@"[^0-9]" withString:@""];
```

which says "no -stringByReplacingOccurrenceoOfRegexwithString  method found" and "Message without a matching method signature will be assumed to return 'id' and accept '.......' as arguments".

How do I get the state and city name from the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `[componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:][1]`. If you supply numbers as the set you will get an array of strings which you can recombine into a numberless string.